# (still unAnswered) django checkbox save yes or no in the database

Tags: javascript, django

```
  <form id="form" name="form">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Asthma" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1"  title="Check if Student have Asthma">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Congenital" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1" title="Check if Student have Congenital Anomalies">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Contact" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1" title="Check if Student use Contact lens">
  </form>
```

i have this code in my html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        // when page is ready
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                             // on form submit
                            $("#form").on('submit', function() {
                                // to each unchecked checkbox
                                $(this + 'input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function () {
                                    // set value 0 and check it
                                    $(this).attr('checked', true).val(0);
                                });
                            })
                        })
                    </script>
```

my problem is everytime i save into my database the result always automatic YES, even i unchecked the checkbox(NO) in the html.
i dont know if i am doing right in my javascript

this is my views.py

```
    Asthma = request.POST['Asthma']
    Congenital = request.POST['Congenital']
    Contact = request.POST['Contact']
V_insert_data = StudentUserMedicalRecord( 
        Asthma=Asthma,
        CongenitalAnomalies=Congenital,
        ContactLenses=Contact
   )
 V_insert_data.save()
```

models.py

```
Asthma=models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
CongenitalAnomalies=models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True, default=False)
ContactLenses=models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True, default=False)
```

html.py
[image]

even i insert record from my html is unchecked(No), the  result always automatic "Yes" in my database, can you please fixed my javascript code? seems like its not working.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: what i mean is everytime i save into my database the result always checked even i unchecked the checkbox in the html

Comment: Is that your code or someone else's? The comments are giving you a clue: there is a loop checking all the checkboxes here: `$(this).attr('checked', true).val(0);`

Comment: i copy this javascript code from the internet but i cant understand, im not really good in javascript

Comment: I posted an answer for you.

Comment: remove these lines from your script                                                                  
      $(this + 'input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function () {
                                    // set value 0 and check it
                                    $(this).attr('checked', true).val(0);
                                });

Comment: sir @Kabali post your answer , okay itry

Comment: nope, same result sir

Comment: @kaito, could you show me your urls.py.

Comment: `$(this).attr('checked', true)` you are setting explicitly to true here

Comment: what should i do sir, to correct my answer and please post your answer sir so i can mark your answer if it is correct

Comment: please sir, till now i didnt solve this problem

Comment: cant say until reproduce I think that may be  the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all javascript. That's converting all 0s to 1. Use this in **views.py**

```
Asthma = request.POST.get('Asthma', 0)  # 0  not '0'
Congenital = request.POST.get('Congenital', 0)  # 0  not '0'
Contact = request.POST.get('Contact', 0)  # 0  not '0'
```

instead of this:

```
Asthma = request.POST['Asthma']
Congenital = request.POST['Congenital']
Contact = request.POST['Contact']
```

**-------------Edit------------------**

**views**

```
Asthma = request.POST.get('Asthma', 0) == '1'
Congenital = request.POST.get('Congenital', 0) == '1'
Contact = request.POST.get('Contact', 0) == '1'
V_insert_data = StudentUserMedicalRecord(
            Asthma=Asthma,
            CongenitalAnomalies=Congenital,
            ContactLenses=Contact
)
V_insert_data.save()
```

**Template**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Asthma" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1"  title="Check if Student have Asthma">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Congenital" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox2" title="Check if Student have Congenital Anomalies">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Contact" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox3" title="Check if Student use Contact lens">
```

Comment: you have to pass integer 0, not string "0". and check if value is 0 store False (or no) otherwise save True (or yes). In python any value other than 0, None is True even "0". @kaito

Comment: can you provide me an example sir?

Comment: @kaito, remember, remove all javascript.

Comment: @kaito. also print all these value to check.

Comment: omg, thank you very much sir, i get it now , but i change some of your answer but dont worry i will mark your answer as correct 1 :)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Remove that Javascript code. You don't need it.

### More details

You don't really need to understand Javascript for this problem. The comments are telling you what is happening, but I will try to clarify:

```
    // when page is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
          // on form submit -> This means that this code will run when the form is submitted
        $("#form").on('submit', function() {
            // to each unchecked checkbox -> This means that each checkbox not checked, will run this code below
            $(this + 'input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function () {
                // set value 0 and check it -> This means that
                $(this).attr('checked', true).val(0);
            });
        })
    })
```

If you want to learn more about it, this code is using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) with the function [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) (used to loop through elements) and the [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function (used to modify a HTML element's attribute).

Comment: seems like this javascript not working, cause its still the same result, or do i have to change my checkedbox id? and value

Comment: @kaito, please refer to my answer again. As I said, the Javascript is not working for you. Just remove it completely.

Comment: i follow your instruction sir but the result is still the same

Answer (score 2):

Cited text taken from this source: https://docs.joomla.org/Talk:Checkbox_form_field_type

**The same problem not only applies to the Joomla project** but also to other web apps or websites using checkboxes (especially note the bold part).

> Special care needs to be taken with saving an unchecked checkbox from
>   a form!! This is a common mistake for component developers thinking
>   Joomla takes care of this. Joomla doesn't, until now. (Problem in
>   Joomla 2.5 still.)
>
> **You see, on saving a form with a checkbox that is unchecked, there is
>   no variable for it in the POST data!** So, it's quite common that the
>   value will NOT be overwritten in your DB, especially if it is already
>   on the value that represents "checked" (e.g. 1 ) on the form.

That's what the JavaScript snippet in your question is for.

```
// when page is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  // on form submit
  $("#form").on('submit', function() {
    // to each unchecked checkbox
    $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function() {
      // set value 0 and check it
      $(this).attr('checked', true).val(0);
    })
  })
})
```

I removed the `$(this +` part because that breaks things.

To clarify: the script checks unchecked checkboxes (to make sure there is a checkbox being posted). But at the same time it changes the value when in `checked` state to 0 (!)

So if you have unchecked boxes, they will represent 0's instead of being left out of POST request data. And when you have checked items yourself it leaves them alone and it will represent as a value of 1 within the POST data for the checkbox(es).

Duplicate ID's are also something you need to prevent. It's not valid HTML5.

Also you have this code:
`request.POST['Asthma']`

I've checked and found it returns a `QueryDict`. Found that on this page:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Example from that page:

`QueryDict('a=1&a=2&c=3')` returns: `<QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': ['3']}>`

This means that e.g. `request.POST['Asthma']` would always return a list, which might be cast to a boolean type. So no matter what's in the list, it might cast to `True` always.

So when you read on it says this:

> `QueryDict.__getitem__(key)¶` Returns the value for the given key. If
>   the key has more than one value, it returns the last value.

So better use `__getitem__(key)` or its alias here:

> `QueryDict.get(key, default=None)¶` Uses the same logic as
>   **getitem**(), with a hook for returning a default value if the key doesn’t exist.

Of course, using the JavaScript snippet is one method you can use. But if you prefer to handle this in your Python code you can just use the `QueryDict` like this:

`Asthma = request.POST.get('Asthma', '0')`

Comment: hi sir, im little confuse on how to use that "QueryDict.get" can you provide an example that relate to my question?

Comment: i tried this ""Asthma = QueryDict.__getitem__('Asthma', '0')""

Comment: and then the error says ""name 'QueryDict' is not defined"" i dont know how to use that QueryDict

Comment: I've added the example. The JavaScript method is valid but providing a default value by means of Python code is valid too. Take your pick. If you are still having this issue you should provide a clearer example, maybe host that example on GitHub or Bitbucket so we can test it better ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for that. Also forget about `method="POST"` in your form (the default method is `GET`).

In addition, for your `views.py`, you need to use `get` method of `request.POST` to prevent `KeyError` exception.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class StudentUserMedicalRecord(models.Model):
    Asthma = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    CongenitalAnomalies = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
    ContactLenses = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import StudentUserMedicalRecord


def sample_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Asthma = request.POST.get('Asthma', '0')
        Congenital = request.POST.get('Congenital', '0')
        Contact = request.POST.get('Contact', '0')
        instance = StudentUserMedicalRecord(
            Asthma=Asthma,
            CongenitalAnomalies=Congenital,
            ContactLenses=Contact
        )
        instance.save()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
  <label>Asthma</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Asthma" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1"  title="Check if Student have Asthma">
  <br>
  <label>Congenital Anomalies</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Congenital" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1" title="Check if Student have Congenital Anomalies">
  <br>
  <label>Contact lens</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Contact" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1" title="Check if Student use Contact lens">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Full project

[Download here](https://gofile.io/?c=aNBVBO)

### Edit (use `ModelForms`)

You can use django's `ModelForm` to prevent such issues with manually making the form.

So in this case, you would have:

**forms.py - beside views.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import StudentUserMedicalRecord


class MedicalRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentUserMedicalRecord
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from sample_app.forms import MedicalRecordForm


def sample_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MedicalRecordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = MedicalRecordForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

find more about them in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: ive got the same result sir

Comment: Did you remove the `javascript`? Also check the full project file I add. I tested it and it works fine for me.

Comment: Is there any `middleware` or `signal` in between? Also please include the full code of your `views.py` file.

Comment: Try removing the value="1" in your template.

Comment: when i removed the value, nothing insert in my database

Comment: So there is something wrong with the `views.py` functionality. Add a `print(request.POST)` before saving the object and show me the result when for the given choices. and also, How do you render the checkbox as a drop-down? maybe there is something wrong there.

Comment: is there any possible answer to my question that used javascript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202387/discussion-between-pedram-parsian-and-kaito).