# django checkbox yes or no

Tags: javascript, django

```
  <form id="form" name="form">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="C" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="python" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Csharp" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox3" >
  </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submit").on('click', function() {
      console.clear()
       $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')==true) 
               console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
             else
               console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

how to save into the database if the user checked it must be yes in the database, or if the checkbox is unchecked it must be no in the database? my problem is everytime I unchecked those three and save it into my database the result in database always automatic checked, i dont know if i am doing right in my javascript

this is my views.py

```
Clang = request.POST["C"]
python = request.POST["python"]
Csharp = request.POST["Csharp"]
V_insert_data = known_Language( 
        Clang =Clang ,
        python =python ,
        Csharp =Csharp 
)
 V_insert_data.save()
```

this is my models.py

```
class known_Language(models.Model):
   Clang = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
   python = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
   Csharp=models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: you have double = in your mode, it is a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django checked if the checkbox is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829631/django-checked-if-the-checkbox-is-true)

Comment: wrong typo hehe

Comment: yes I already saw that problem sir and none of them works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need javascript for that,

```
<form id="form" name="form">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="C" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="python" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Csharp" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox3" >
  </form>
```

and do this to your views.py heres the example:

```
Asthma = request.POST.get('Asthma', 1) == '0'
Congenital = request.POST.get('Congenital', 1) == '0'
Contact = request.POST.get('Contact', 1) == '0'
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot have `duplicate id's`. change them, and also by `default` the checkbox are `checked`, so you can change the `value to 0` if you want `unchecked` in first load.

```
<form id="form" name="form">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="C" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="python" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Csharp" data-form-field="Option" class="form-check-input display-7" id="checkbox3" >
  </form>
```

Comment: the thing is, you are not posting any data. either use form or use ajax to post data. check how to post data from html to django view

Comment: but how sir? I don't know how do it

Comment: search this in google `how to post data from html to django view`